# Creator of a column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to find the creator of a column in SQL Server?
I checked `sys.column` table but only getting the created and modified date. With these two fields I also need the Creator of the column.

By Creator I mean the userid which is used to login to sql server.

Comment: which version of sql server? This link might help (even though it is for SQL Server 2005) [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server).

Comment: you cant capture it,unless you have an audit

Comment: using sql server 2008

Comment: [You can find your question related discussion in this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server)

Comment: you can't, unless you have something implemented at the SQLserver that can help you on getting those results or you can take a look at the following code and implement something on your end if it fits on your environment. [find-who-when-a-sql-view-is-dropped.....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653284/find-who-when-a-sql-view-is-dropped-in-sql-server/35654280#35654280)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you can not but if you change the column recently than you can try to find it in the below way

[image]

This report provides a history of all committed DDL statement executions within the Database recorded by the default trace.